# LocalStorage: get every value from each key

Tags: html, angular, loops, typescript, local-storage

I want to go through every key and get the `name` value from each key.
This is how my LocalStorage looks like.

> key: 3 Value:
>   {"name":"Kevin","country":"Canada","about":"Test","image":""}
>
> key: 4 Value:
>   {"name":"Homer","country":"Canada","about":"Test","image":""}

I want to getboth of these names and add them to my array. I tried it with this method:

```
for(var key in localStorage){
   let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
   this.users.push(user);
}
```

Error I get is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1

Comment: Are you using `JSON.stringify` before you store a value using `setItem`?

Comment: Missing opening quotes for _name_

Comment: yes I am `localStorage.setItem(this.getId(), JSON.stringify(value));`

Comment: are You store multiple `key #` objects in local storage?

Comment: show what you get from `localStorage.getItem(key)`

Answer (score 3):

```
 var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
 keys.forEach(key=>{
  var json_str =localStorage.getItem(key)
   try {
       var abc = JSON.parse(json_str);
       this.user = abc;
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

when you say **I want to getboth of these names**, i don't get it but either way you can try something like:

```
var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    var key = keys[i];
    console.log(key, localStorage[key]);
    //store here "both names" where you want them
    //you can also access each element with localStorage[key].name, localStorage[key].country, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a refinement of [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46340534/1915893).

Just enumerate all of the values (The keys themselves do not matter) in `localStorage` that have a `name` property that is a string. Then return that array.

Based on your own answer, you likely have inconsistent mutable state as moving your temporary variable to instance scope should not impact your situation.

```
function getUsers() {
  return Object.values(localStorage)
    .map(json => {
      try {
        return JSON.parse(json);
      }
      catch (e) {
        return undefined;
      }
    })
    .filter((user?: any): user is {name: string} => user && typeof user.name === 'string');
}

const users = getUsers();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using my library [`ngx-store`](https://github.com/zoomsphere/ngx-store) to deal with localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies and a bit more in Angular. To achieve what you want you will be able to store whole array in storage or just use code like the below with your current data structure:

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-store';

export class Example {
  public users: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(public localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
    this.localStorageService.utility.forEach((value, key) => this.users.push(value));
  }
}
```

Really, it can be just that simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `hasOwnProperty('propertyName')` to check name available or not in object. Then perform the operation that you want.

```js
let localStorage = {
    "key1": {"name":"Kevin","country":"Canada","about":"Test","image":""},
    "key2": {"name":"Homer","country":"Canada","about":"Test","image":""}
}
for(let key of Object.keys(localStorage)){
    if(localStorage[key].hasOwnProperty('name')){
        console.log(localStorage[key]['name']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator to get all localstorage as a new object

```
const items = { ...localStorage };
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    const  allItems = []
    const keys = Object.keys(window.localStorage);  // all keys

    keys.forEach(key=> {
      const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key) + '');  //item with type Object
      allItems.push(item);
    });
    console.log(allItems) // arry of object
```

Answer (score -2):

I manage to solve it, was a simple error by always initializing a new `let user` inside the loop.

I moved out the `user` and the rest of the code works.

```
user: any;

  getUsers():void{
    for(var key in localStorage){
      this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      this.users.push(this.user);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is definitely not related to _SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1_

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Having an erroneous property named `user` that refers to an arbitrary element of `users` _if and only if_ `getUsers` is called under certain circumstances is bad design. There is nothing wrong with the local variable declaration in your original code. If this fixes your error, you have a serious bug somewhere else.