# How to assign an object to local storage instated of assigning with every single item?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I want to assign to the local storage , I mean can you loop over it ? any idea how to implement this ?
The end result is the keys in the object must be keys as well in the local storage after using the setitem, I sure know how set and get singular items but in other words I want to mount and object on an empty local storage object.

```js
 const data = JSON.parse(object); // a prev localstroage object 
 console.log(data);
 localStorage.setItem(...Object.keys(data), ...Object.values(data));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `JSON.stringify(data);` in order to store object in local storage.

Make sure you create your complete object in JavaScript itself (as per your requirement). And then once your object is ready, use `JSON.stringify` method to save objects in your local storage.

And to retreive back the data you will use `JSON.parse()` to get back the Object and then you can use any JavaScript methods to perform your tasks as per the requirement.

Comment: Sure , but what about the keys I mean my object has at least 10 keys !! How to push them at once !

Comment: Could you please add the syntax then in to your answer .. the syntax of setting the object with keys I want my object keys to by keys as well in the local storage rather than values…the model of ls should look exactly like the incoming object.

Comment: Dear Friend @Richardson I am not exactly sure about what your requirement it Buddy. Can you give me more context. So that I can help you out :)

Comment: You need to do something like this my friend
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340004/localstorage-get-every-value-from-each-key

Comment: lets say the local storages is empty, and my obj that i want to push to ls is the following , {Numbers : [1,2,3]}, i am not talking about parsing but about how to populate key values in local storage according to my obj that i want to push I want the local storage to look exactly like this  Keys must be numbers and values must be [1,2,3] but how can achieve this in one single action ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 //To set
 const obj = {
   key: "Hello World"
 }
 const strObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
 localStorage.setItem('strObj', strObj);

 //To get
 const strObjFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('strObj')
 const objFromStorage = JSON.parse(strObjFromStorage)
 console.log(objFromStorage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` :

```js
// save object to localStorage
const myobj = {
    x: 1,
    y: 6
};
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(myobj));
// fetch date as object from localStorage
let data = JSON.parse(localStorate.getItem('key'));
```

Comment: How would the final object look like in local storage ! I want my object to take over local storage in your answer your are stating key then the key with have the object of x and y, I want the x y to be at top level keys in the keys column rather than in value !!